# Adding another model to a form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to setup a form which draws in fields from 2 models.

I tired to add the model's together like below but keep getting an error.

```
model = Server, Tag
```

The backend admin picks up the relationship between the 2 models and I can update it from the backend however through the form I'm having trouble combining the two together.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.forms import ModelForm

from servers.models import Server
from servers.models import Tag

class ServerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Server, Tag
        fields = ['name', 'order', 'first_name']

def server_list(request, template_name='servers/server_list.html'):
    servers = Server.objects.all()
    data = {}
    data['object_list'] = servers
    return render(request, template_name, data)

def server_create(request, template_name='servers/server_form.html'):
    form = ServerForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('server_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})

def server_update(request, pk, template_name='servers/server_form.html'):
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=pk)
    form = ServerForm(request.POST or None, instance=server)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('server_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})

def server_delete(request, pk, template_name='servers/server_confirm_delete.html'):
    server = get_object_or_404(Server, pk=pk)    
    if request.method=='POST':
        server.delete()
        return redirect('server_list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'object':server})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

class Server(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('server_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

server_form.py

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<!--     {{ form.as_p }}  this brings in the whole form-->

    Name <br>
    {{ form.name }} <br>
    Order <br>
    {{ form.order }} <br>
    First name <br>
    tag <br>
    {{ form.tag }} <br> <!--trying to get tag to work through this form-->
    {{ form.first_name }} <br><br>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

I'm trying to get the {{ form.tag }} part to work and the form to recognize the relationship.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use this syntax to use multiple model in a form. Admin backend makes extensive use of InlineModelFormSet to handle such relations. Take a look to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Thanks for the info. I see how InlineModelFormSet handles relationships with foreign keys. However can't manage to get it to work properly with my model and views. Might have to start from scratch and build it from there.

Comment: When dealing with tags, I think the best option is to work with a CharField in which you will enter some coma separated tags, manage the UI via jquery tagit and autocomplete (for example) and handles the result in a clean_tags method in your form, methods that returns a list of tags by splitting them by coma and handle the save logic in save() method. If it sounds good for you, update your initial question so I can update my answer.